# "Роковой" и "речевой" — однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Относятся ли прилагательные *роковой* и *речевой* к однокоренным?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему. (Из Справки о сайте.)

Answer (score 1):

А зачем нам прилагательные? Мы с существительными (от коих они происходят) попробуем разобраться.

> Относятся ли прилагательные роковой и речевой к однокоренным?

Сейчас однозначно нет.

[Праслав. *rokъ "срок", связано с реку́, речь (см.)](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-11232.htm)

Но у нас же не о сроке/годе речь?

[РЕЧЬ](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C)

> От праслав. *rěčь, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск.,
>   ст.-слав. рѣчь (др.-греч. ῥῆμα, λόγος, διάνοια); русск. речь, укр.
>   річ, ре́чі, белор. реч «вещь», болг. реч, сербохорв. ри̏jеч «слово»,
>   словенск. rе̣̑č (род. п. -ȋ) «вещь», чешск. řеč «речь», словацк. rеč —
>   то же, польск. rzесz «вещь», в.-луж. rěč «речь, язык», н.-луж. rěс —
>   то же.

[РОК](http://www.slovorod.ru/etym-shansky/shan-r.htm)

> Общеслав. Производное (с перегласовкой е/о) от *rekti (> речь). См.
>   обречь. Рок "судьба" < "предсказанное", ср. однобразные лат. fatum
>   "судьба" (см. фатализм) и fari "говорить".
>
> ---

[Пророк, урок, речь... (Из истории русских слов)](http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/28_76)

> ...При формировании общеславянского языка (а это было за несколько
>   веков до христианизации Руси, Польши и других славянских территорий и
>   государств) в основе таких слов с первоначальным, достаточно
>   расплывчатым значением, как *rek-ti (глагол) и *rek-tis (отглагольное
>   существительное) лежало представление (мифологический концепт)
>   «колдовать с помощью речи, а также с помощью глаз», откуда в
>   дальнейшем появились исчезнувшие затем русские слова *урочить*
>   «околдовать, назначить», *урок* «колдовство», *сурочитъ* «освободить
>   от колдовства, вылечить заговoрами»...